# Basic Python syntax error for greater/less than symbols

Tags: python

I am teaching myself how to code python. In this problem I kept on receiving syntax errors for my 0 greater than b less or equal to x line. Saying it was an invalid syntax. Why is this the case?

I could use the range(x) function to get a list of numbers but this way seems like it should be quicker and easier. Thanks for the help

```
def factorial(x):
    if x==0:
        return 1
    elif x>0:
        b=int
        total = 1
        for 0<b<=x:
            total*=b
        return total
```

Comment: `0<b<=x`? Maybe `(0 < b) && (b <= x)`, but what's the poitn of doing that kind of comparison as a `for` loop?

Comment: I'm quite confused here ... What do you expect `for 0<b<=x` to be doing (considering that `b` is the type `int` ...)?

Comment: @MarcB -- Python doesn't have an `&&` operator.  `0 < b <= x` is a completely valid logical expression in python.  However, `for <logical_expression>` is not a valid statement in python (it's not even clear to me what OP is going for here).

Comment: I'm pretty sure SimSimmer was hoping it would be understood as "for each integer b with 0<b<=x". Which would be a very nice thing for some programming language to support, but it happens that Python doesn't.

Comment: Sure, python's got a way to do that... `for i in xrange(1, x+1): ...`

Comment: Off-topic: `b=int` is useless here. You don't have to declare variables in Python (and that is an assignment, not a declaration)

Comment: Oh yes (and I said that in my answer to the question) but the point is that it doesn't let you do it implicitly by just saying what inequalities `b` has to satisfy.

Comment: (I have a feeling that I tongue-half-in-cheekily proposed exactly such a feature in comp.lang.python a decade or two ago, but of course I can't find the relevant post now.)

Answer (score 3):

Either you mean `if`, not `for` (in which case the solution is to replace `for` with `if`) or else you are hoping that your code will iterate over, maybe, all integers `b` in the given range (in which case the answer is that `for` doesn't work like that; you need to construct an explicit object to iterate over, e.g. using `range`).

I suspect the latter, since you haven't really given `b` a value. (Well, actually, you have, but probably not the way you intended. You have made `b` equal to an object that represents *the integer type*. If that doesn't make sense to you, ignore it for now.)

I'm afraid Python isn't clever enough for you to say "`b` is an integer; please do something for each possible value between 0 and `x`" -- which I think is what you were hoping for. But, e.g., `range(1,x+1)` is an object representing all the integers from 1 (inclusive) to `x+1` (exclusive), and you can use a `for` loop to do something for each of those.

Answer (score 1):

`for` must be followed by an iterable. The correct syntax is:

```
for variable in iterable:
```

In your case you should generate some iterable that goes from `1` to `x`. To do this you should use `range(1,x+1)` (Or `xrange` if you are in python 2)

Your code should look like this:

```
for b in range(1, x+1):
    total *= b
```

Also, `b = int` is not what you think. This is not a declaration, it makes `b` not a variable of type `int` but actually the type itself. In python you can't restrict a variable to keep being of certain type (At least not in a simple way, AFAIK)